# Show power divergence statistic converges to LRT statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, probability, self-study, categorical-data, convergence

This is a homework problem out of Agresti's Analysis of Categorical Data (1.34b)

For counts $\{n_j\}$ the power divergence statistic for testing goodness of fit is $$ \dfrac{2}{\lambda(\lambda+1)}\sum_{i=1}^m n_i[(n_i/\hat{\mu}_i)^\lambda-1] \quad \text{for }-\infty < \lambda < \infty$$

As $\lambda$ approaches 0, show that it converges to the LRT statistic $G^2 = 2\sum_{i=1}^m n_i\log{\left(\dfrac{n_i}{\hat{\mu}_i}\right)}$.

I have no idea where to start. One of the original papers that discussed the Power Divergence Statistic simply states this as a fact (http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/Exotic/1Robustness/CressieRead%20JRSSB%2084.pdf)

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem boils down to showing:

$$\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow 0} \frac{y^\lambda-1}{\lambda}=\log y$$

(it's rather easy to show your required result from there; this should hopefully be a result you've seen before, but it doesn't matter if you haven't).

Is that sufficient for you to get somewhere, or do you need a hint on how to do that limit I gave?

---

Since Benjamin seems to have it now, I will expand a bit:

The above result (which should at least be familiar to many of us from the Box-Cox transformations) follows either by l'Hopital's rule, or by writing $y^\lambda = \exp(\lambda \log y)$ and expanding the series, cancelling out what can be cancelled and taking the limit. Once you have it, the original result follows by using the above (with $y = n_i/\hat{\mu}_i$) and then all that's left is the multiplicative term $\frac{1}{\lambda+1}$ at the front, which is simple to deal with as $\lambda \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was a bit rusty on my analysis facts.

Comment: If you've ever used Box-Cox transformations, you should be able to remember it.